# How to make the debug function of haskell-idea-plugin work properly

Tags: debugging, haskell, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, ghc-mod

I installed haskell-idea-plugin to make a Haskell IDE.

The plugin can do the following things as claimed on https://github.com/Atsky/haskell-idea-plugin.

- Haskell syntax highlight
- Cabal syntax highlight
- Error checking with ghc-modi.
- Simple completion based on ghc-modi
- Show type of symbol (Ctrl + Shift + T, or ⌘ + Shift + T on mac)
- Build of cabal projects
- Installation of cabal packages
- REPL

But when I tried to debug the following simple Haskell file

```
module Main where

main = do
    str <- getLine
    putStrLn $ str++str
```

it reported: `Debug execution error: Internal error occured while executing debug process for untitled`

And here is my Haskell-debugger configuration:
[image]

I also tried other options but it didn't work.

And here is my environment:

1. Ubuntu14.10
2. oracle-jdk6.0
3. IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.16
4. haskell-idea-plugin
5. ghc-mod
6. remote-debugger

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am under windows, I got the similar error. The steps that worked for me to resolve the error:

1. Try run `ghc-modi.exe` from the command line. It were times when it resulted in error

   `ghc-modi.exe: C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\ghc-mod: createProcess: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

   This is fixed by recompiling and installing `ghc-mod` from the [sources](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod), I guess `ghc-modi` contains the hard path to `ghc-mod`, and the compiled files are not movable across different machines.
2. It seems that the `remote-debugger` has the same hard dependency on the position in the filesystem. During one of my previous installations I copied it from different machine and got `C:\Portable\ghc-7.10.1\lib\settings: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`.
   The fix is, again, rebuild `remote-debugger` from the [sources](https://github.com/octomarat/HaskellDebugger) on the current machine.
3. Of course all these executables should be accessible in `PATH`.
4. After that I created `hello` project from scratch and the (remote) debugging worked just fine.